# Proving p is a Metric on X

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have an exercise which I cannot get my head around. 
Essentially $X$ is a non-empty set and $p: X^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies

(1) $0 \leq p(x,y) < +\infty$

(2) $p(x,y) = 0 \iff x=y$ and

(3) $p(x,y) \leq p(x,z) + p(y,z)$.

How would I go about proving that p is a metric on X? Clearly (1), and (2) are the first two axioms and it seems that proving symmetry would automatically prove the triangle inequality by using the relation $p(y,z) = p(z,y)$, but there doesn't seem to be a way of proving this, as it is an axiom. Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. [Please read this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117) to learn how to properly format your post. (I just edited yours -- look how I did it to get an idea)

Answer (score 2):

With $z=x$ we get

$$p(x,y)\le p(x,x)+p(y,x)=p(y,x)$$
and interchange the role of $x$ and $y$ we get
$$p(y,x)\le p(x,y)$$
and the result follows easily.